# takeUntil optimized cache and network method with Retrofit, RxJava and Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to implement the optimized cache and network method using `RxJava`'s `takeUntil` operator to get data from server. I am using a Gson model to parse the JSON responses from the API .

I am getting stuck at retrieving data from server due to using Gson model. as the returned type is mismatch for both Netwrok Request and Disk cache.

I've been testing several methods but didn't succeed to get it right.

**ApiService.java**

```
@GET(ApiConstants.GET_QUESTIONS_URL) Observable<RequestResponse> getQuestions();
```

**ineteractor.java**

```
   public void performGetElQuestions(String query, QuestionsRequestServerCallback callback) {

 getFreshNetworkData()//
        .publish(network ->//
            Observable.merge(network,//
                getCachedDiskData().takeUntil(network)))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Question>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete() {
            callback.onQuestionsReady(mQuestionsList);
          }
          @Override
          public void onError(Throwable e) {
            callback.onQuestionsFailed();
          }

          @Override
          public void onNext(Question question) {
            // mQuestionsList is an arraylist
            mQuestionsList.add(question);
          }
        });
```

**interactor.java**

```
private Observable<Question> getFreshNetworkData() {
        return apiService.getQuestions()
              .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
              .doOnSubscribe((data) -> new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())//
                    .post(() -> adapterSubscriptionInfo.add("(network) subscribed")))//
              .doOnComplete(() -> new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())//
                    .post(() -> adapterSubscriptionInfo.add("(network) completed")));
    }
```

**Cached Data**

```
     private Observable<Question> getCachedDiskData() {
    List<Question> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //get cached data from SQLite or disk

    return Observable.fromIterable(list)//
        .doOnSubscribe((data) -> new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())//
            .post(() -> Timber.d("(disk) cache subscribed")))//
        .doOnComplete(() -> new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())//
            .post(() -> Timber.d("(disk) cache completed")));
  }
```

Gson model parser

**RequestResponse.java**

```
Public class RequestResponse {

    @SerializedName("questions")
    ArrayList<Question> questions;

    public ArrayList<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
}
```

Thanks :) .

Comment: What is the json you are getting from the server?

Comment: Hey @iagreen, https://gist.github.com/alouanemed/65fb8069d15edfe1cc49dbe0973111f2

Comment: Please show error stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I use realm and use advantages of RXJava concat + take(1), each time I retrieve data and cache it but if innet conection is slow cached data is always ready.
Code example for Country entity:

```
 public Observable<ArrayList<Pair<Country,City>>> queryAllAndCopyOrLoad(){
    return Observable.concat(

        Observable.just(storageInteractor.queryAllAndCopySync(Country.class))
            .filter(RxPretty::notEmpty)
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),

        networkService.serverApi()
            .getCountries()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(countries -> storageInteractor.deleteAllAndPut(countries, Country.class))
            .doOnNext(countries -> firstTime = false))

        .take(1)
        .flatMap(this::transformToCityCountryPair);
  }
```